# ebay trading api memory usage

Tags: memory-leaks, ebay-api

I'm working on a program to retrieve some data(getuserlist calls) from eBay service, I use multiThreads(8 threads) to fasten the progress, while it always use almost 2000+ mb memory to process the requests and don't even release these memory after all requests are done. I'm pretty sure these memory usage is not from my own data in the program. Does anyone know how to get rid of them?

Comment: What is your metric for memory usage?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: If you are running on Linux, can you update your question to include the output of the following command? "cat /proc/<your-pid>/smaps"

Comment: Which programming language do you use? Do you use a official eBay SDK, which one?